# Android SDK postDelayed API

Tags: android

I have a little doubt about how the postDelayed works:

The Android SDK documentation says:

> if the looper is quit before the delivery time of the message occurs
>   then the message will be dropped.

Let's say I queued postDelayed to 5000 milliseconds but the device went to sleep before the timer expired if my Service hits OnResume when it wakes up will postDelayed be in the queue or has it been discarded?

Comment: This is really a general Android SDK issue.  This is not related to Facebook Android SDK.

Comment: ops! sorry the tag was incorrect and I did not notice.